# How can a server know which client is connecting it while the client is using getInputStream:outputStream:?

Tags: nsnetservice

I am using hotspot to communicate with iPhone, I publish netservice and connect each other. While every client can find many devices, when one of them connect my device by using getInputStream:outputStream:, how can I know which one is connecting me? PS:I have tried to resolve IP, but IP address can change any time.

Answer (score 0):

Make your hotspot send some defined credentials (such as a host name) on the first attempt to connect. When accepting an input stream, check, if these data are provided and you're all set.